# Error while trying to deploy a Spring project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I got this error when i tried to deploy the spring project in Spring-Tool-Suite 2.9.1.

```
7 Apr, 2012 5:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [D:\IDE\springsource\sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
7 Apr, 2012 5:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [D:\IDE\springsource\sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
7 Apr, 2012 5:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [D:\IDE\springsource\sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
7 Apr, 2012 5:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [D:\IDE\springsource\sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:236)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:425)
```

Can someone tell me what the cause of this is?How can i fix this error?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina`

Comment: You don't have read permissions to the `D:\IDE\springsource\sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\lib` filder.